# implement abstract adapter class in MainActivity

Tags: android

I have an abstract MonthAdapter class

> **MonthAdapter.java**

```
public MonthAdapter(Context c, int month, int year, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    this.mContext = c;
    this.mMonth = month;
    this.mYear = year;
    this.mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(mYear, mMonth, 1);
    this.mCalendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.mDisplayMetrics = metrics;
    populateMonth();
}
protected abstract void onDate(int[] date, int position, View item);

}
```

And I want to implement it on MainActivity's gridview adapter like this :

```
mGridView.setAdapter(new MonthAdapter(this, param[1], param[2], metrics));
```

How to implement this abstract class, since abstract class cannot instantiated inside MainActivity and also main class cannot inherits directly to abstract class because MainActivity is already extended to Activity.
Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mGridView.setAdapter(new MonthAdapter(this, param[1], param[2], metrics){
            @Override
            public void onDate(int[] date, int position, View item){
            }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class who extend your abstract class, for example :

```
public class MonthAdapterImpl extends MonthAdapter {

    public MonthAdapter(Context c, int month, int year, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        super(c, month, year, metrics);
    }

    @Override
    protected abstract void onDate(int[] date, int position, View item) {
       // the code
    };
}
```

Hope this helps.